# Add userControl2 to Panel2 from userControl1 button in Panel1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

How to get userControl2 from button click on userControl1 into panel2?

Pressing the button `New` shows `userControl1` control on `Panel1`, but I want to show `usercontrol2` by pressing `userControl1` button to `panel2` `userControl2`. I couldn't do it.

```
private void btnNewDay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  frmMain main = new frmMain();
  main.panel2.Controls.Clear();
  userControls.ucNewDay newDay = new userControls.ucNewDay();
  main.panel2.Controls.Add(newDay);
  main.userControlcontrol = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new form with `new frmMain();`. What you need is to get a handle of the current form. You can do that by simply using the `this` keyword, but this is even optional and you don't have to use anything. However, in a user control, `this` refers to the control. In this case use the `Parent` property.

Change the first line:

```
frmMain main = new frmMain();
```

to:

```
frmMain main = (frmMain)this.Parent;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `FindForm()` method:

```
frmMain main = (frmMain)this.FindForm();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I have been looking answers for this about 1 week